# I want to send two email with different view page using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send two different emails with two different view blade files for submitting a single form.

**My Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;


use App\Mail\quickQuoteMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\sysmaster;

use App\Mail\contactEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function contactEmail(Request $request)
    {

        $data = array(
          'ContactPerson'=>  $request->FullName,
          'ContactEmail'=>   $request->Email,
          'ContactNumber'=>   $request->Number,
          'ContactMessage'=> $request->Enquiry,
        );

        $token = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');

        if(strlen($token)>0)
        {

            $quickQuoteemail = sysmaster::where('sysm_val_type', 'Contact_Email')->where('sysm_def_id', 'to')->first();

            $quickQuote = sysmaster::where('sysm_val_type', 'Contact_Email')->where('sysm_def_id', 'Cc')->first();

            if ($quickQuote->sysm_value!=null) {
                Mail::to($quickQuoteemail->sysm_value)->cc([$quickQuote->sysm_value, $request->Email])->send(new contactEmail($data));
            } else {
                Mail::to($quickQuoteemail->sysm_value)->cc($request->Email)->send(new contactEmail($data));
            }

            return redirect()->back()->with('message','Thank you for contact us.');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('message','Please make sure your not a robot');
        }




    }
}
```

**Mail Function**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\sysmaster;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class contactEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $quickQuoteemail = sysmaster::where('sysm_val_type','Contact_Email')->where('sysm_def_id','from')->first();

        return $this->from($quickQuoteemail->sysm_value,$this->data['ContactPerson'])
            ->subject('Contact Us Enquiry')->view('email_contact_quote')->with('data',$this->data);
    }
}
```

I have another view blade file there (contact_email_company) How can I include that view with this function and this UI only will send for the company top one have to go for the only client please help how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic view name You can pass view name in `$data` Mail class

Change below in your controller function:

```
if ($quickQuote->sysm_value!=null) {
 $data['view_name'] = 'email_contact_quote';
 Mail::to($quickQuoteemail->sysm_value)->cc([$quickQuote->sysm_value, $request->Email])->send(new contactEmail($data));
}
else {
 $data['view_name'] = 'contact_email_company';
  Mail::to($quickQuoteemail->sysm_value)->cc($request->Email)->send(new contactEmail($data));
}
```

And in mail class change as below: take view name from `$data`,

```
return $this->from($quickQuoteemail->sysm_value,$this->data['ContactPerson'])
    ->subject('Contact Us Enquiry')->view($this->data['view_name'])->with('data',$this->data);
```